# Unable to find bookmarked folders after each power off

Tags: 22.04, bookmarks

I use ubuntu 22.04 LTS, and my problem is that after the power off, all folders that are bookmarked miss their locations and it gives such an error:

[image]

Interestingly, if I open the partition that bookmarked folders belong to, the problem will be resolved and relinked to the missed address.

Comment: So to make sure, after seeing this message, you look into your Downloads folder, and the folder Sample3 is still there?

Comment: Yes, it is still there, and it is interesting that when I browse the bookmarked address again, the error is resolved, and it works again. It seems bookmarked address is held in cache and needs to refresh.

Comment: Interestingly, if I open the partition that a bookmarked folder belongs to, the problem will be resolved and relinked to the missed address.

Comment: Then I think you did not provide us all information. Downloads is normally on the system partition or the home partition

Comment: I didn't say that it happens just for 'downloads' folder, it happens for all bookmarked folders. I recently realized that after each shutdown this problem happens. (I updated my question)